# Does a Model in MVC Need To Be a Class Or is That Just a Common Pattern?

Tags: model-view-controller, model

I realize I'm conflating / confusing two different topics, but it seems like in most popular MVC frameworks that I've come across the model is a class / object-oriented (and uses some sort of ORM or ODM that I might not want to use).

My question is: If I split my files into models, views, and controllers, but my model is **simply a separate file** that handles business logic, validates data and handles communication with a database... but I do it in my own way that isn't object-oriented... and maybe just uses super simplistic `if` statements for validation... is that still considered a model? Would that still be considered MVC?

Does the model need to be a class / object-oriented or is that just a super common pattern / preference?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general "Model" refers to your [Business Object Model (BOM)](http://sce.uhcl.edu/helm/rationalunifiedprocess/process/modguide/md_bom.htm). If you subscribe to [Domain Driven Design (DDD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) then your Models in a Model View Controller (MVC) architecture will be representative of your BOMs as classes or interfaces. Those BOMs may also be your classes in an Object Relational Map architecture. Since it is better for an interface to be a description of what something can do and a class as a description of what something is, you would tend to see your Models represented as classes rather than interfaces. In terms of what "logic" is allowed inside of those model classes it is really up to you and your team. For example, while it is typical to put data validation in Models you may want to abstract those rules to a separate data validation class that your model uses. There is typically not a black and white rule about where business logic goes but it is generally considered best practice for each class to have a single responsibility based on the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) as part of the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) model. From my experience when I have called "Model" classes things that were not the Business Object Models, like a "RepositoryModel", it can be confusing about where the code representation of the data model was. Instead I recommend using the word "Model" to be reserved for things which end users are familiar with and avoid the word "Model" for things they cannot.